# Overflow:visible collapses div height to zero

Tags: css, wordpress, overflow, twenty-ten-theme

I'm editing the css of a Wordpress theme (twentyten)

This is my HTML structure:

```
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="header"></div>
        <div id="main">
            <div id="filtri_di_ricerca"><img></div>
            <div id="container">
                <div id="content"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="footer"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

and this is my CSS:

```
#main {
    position:relative;
    background:#fff;
    overflow:visible;
}

#filtri_di_ricerca img {
    position: absolute;
    top: -96px
}

#filtri_di_ricerca {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 20px;
    width: 250px;
    background-color: #E6E6E6;
}
```

I need to overlap the `#main` div with the `#filtri_di_ricerca` div, but when I set `overflow:visible` on `#main his height` collapses to zero...
I can still see `#container` and `#content` but the background of `#main` is no more visible... I see `#body`'s background instead.

Answer (score 2):

This is caused by how the height of a div is calculated. It all depends on the content, if not set fixed.
Due to overflow:visible, the content is not needed to fit in the div. So the div's height is set to zero.

Set some fixed height to the div and it should stay at that height.

Answer (score 2):

You need to clear the floats for your #main div.

```
/* For modern browsers */
#main:before,
#main:after {
    content:"";
    display:table;
}
#main:after {
    clear:both;
}
/* For IE 6/7 (trigger hasLayout) */
#main {
    zoom:1;
}
```

[Read more on clearfix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/211383/which-method-of-clearfix-is-best)

Answer (score 0):

#filtri_di_ricerca's CSS position is "absolute" (so get out of the natural flow) and #container dont have any content.

Try to add some content in #content and set a padding-top of #content equal to the #filtri_di_ricerca's height